# Sublime Text 3 Automatic Selecting Build System for MultiMarkdown File

Tags: sublimetext3, multimarkdown

I want to create a build system for Sublime Text 3 that will automatically run on any file that ends in ".mmd". I understand from the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html) that the "selector" option provides this feature; however, I'm not able to get it to work properly. Below is my current build system (I'm doing this for use with [Scriptorium](https://github.com/jasedit/scriptorium)). The commented out lines show other arguments I've tried to pass to "selector".

```
{
    "cmd": ["scriptorium", "build"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.markdown.multimarkdown",
    // "selector": "source.multimarkdown",
    // "selector": "source.mmd",
}
```

If I manually select it as the build system, it works as expected, but if I try building using the Automatic build system, it says no build system available. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Under View-> Syntax, .mmd files open under Markdown -> MultiMarkdown, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct scope selector to use for MultiMarkdown is `text.html.markdown.multimarkdown`, which can be seen by creating a new, empty tab in ST, setting the syntax to Markdown -> MultiMarkdown and then going to the Tools menu -> Developer -> Show Scope Name.

Comment: Answered the question AND now I know where to find it in the future. Thank you!